# VBA code to pass parameter of ms-access form to query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I can't seem to figure out a good way to code this into my VBA macro. I'm using Access. I have a form that's serving as a 'login' it Dlookups to make sure the user is within a user table. Once it's confirmed that the user is within the user table, I want it to run a query on another table with the criteria of the username.

This is the criteria of my username field on my query referenced table:

```
[Forms]![LoginForm].[txtUserName]
```

This is the Macro of my login form click button

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click()

    Dim User As String
    Dim UserLevel As Integer
    Dim TempPass As String
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim TempID As String


    If IsNull(Me.txtUserName) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter UserName", vbInformation, "Username required"
        Me.txtUserName.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter Password", vbInformation, "Password required"
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    Else
        If (IsNull(DLookup("UserLogin", "tblUser", "UserLogin = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "' And UserPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
            MsgBox "Invalid Username or Password!"
        Else
            TempID = Me.txtUserName.Value
            UserName = DLookup("[UserName]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
            UserLevel = DLookup("[UserSecurity]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
            TempPass = DLookup("[UserPassword]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
            UserLogin = DLookup("[UserLogin]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
            DoCmd.Close
            If (TempPass = "password") Then
                MsgBox "Please change Password", vbInformation, "New password required"
                DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUserinfo", , , "[UserLogin] = " & UserLogin
            Else
                'open different form according to user level
                 DoCmd.OpenQuery "ClockDefectRun", , acReadOnly
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Whenever I run this, My query opens, but it asks for the field as if it doesn't exist in my forms. How can I pass this programmatically?

Comment: Try to hide the first window(form) instead of closing it until you are done with your parameters. Then you can close all windows(forms).

Comment: Well, I do hope you are not planning to save passwords raw in database...

Comment: And why "look up" UserLogin which you already have: `UserLogin = DLookup("[UserLogin]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")`.

Comment: Aside: `Excel macros <> Access macros`. So, there is no Access macro posted here.

Comment: @VincentG...Correct but it is not called an *Access macro* but an Access module. Access macros are specific non-VBA objects. Do not conflate with Excel terminology.